# Can I have two long term work permits for two EU countries

Tags: residence-cards, work-permit

I am a non-EU highly skilled worker, working full time in Germany. I have found another full time job in another EU country in the night shift (easily manageable as hybrid that is option to work from home and sometimes from the office is there) and I have the work permit to work over there as well. I am not a permanent resident of Europe. In order to set up bank, I will register my residence in the other EU country as well so it means that I will hold registered residences in two EU countries. Can I work in two EU countries at the same time while my tax being deducted in both the countries?

Comment: It depends on the countries involved and their own specific rules (would you add that information to your question). It is usually *theoretically* possible, but practictally unmanageable.

Comment: Check whether you actually need the second work permit. I think you need a German work permit to be allowed to work while physically in Germany, and any money that you make from work while physically in Germany is taxed in Germany. Of course you need to check for the rules of the other country as well. Registering a non-existing residence in another country might cause trouble.

Comment: Can't your second employer pay your wages into your German bank account?